# Python updating csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am new in python world and I need help to update a csv file:

file.csv:

```
Number  Value  Value2
  1     3.14
  2     4.37
  3     5.23
```

I want to update `Value2` with : `value1 * 1000`

I have tried this :

```py
with open (iFile, "r") as csv_file:
    value1= []
    value2=[]

    fieldList = []

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:    

        value1= row[2]
        value2= row[2]*1000

    fieldList.append([Number, value1, value2])

with open(iFile,"a") as file:             
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(fieldList) 

f.close()
```

Comment: Can you share the data to be more clear? If Value2 and Value1 are columns then you can simply do df[Value2] = df[Value1]*1000

Comment: OP is new to python they are almost definitely not using pandas. @MChakir can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: The Number value1 and value 2 are columns

Comment: DIST(Km) value1 value2
1 0.062062356 
2 0.096578023 
3 0.087960828 
4 0.077553424 
5 0.076567892 
6 0.075297993 
7 0.070460196 
8 0.063264443

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable approach would be to use the csv module since it will handle any special formatting needed for other fields. In your example code you are overwriting value1 and value2 on each iteration, you want to use the `append` function to add elements to a list.

```py
import csv

result = []
with open('input.csv') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)

    for x in data:
        x['Value2'] = float(x['Value']) * 1000
        result.append(x)

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=result[0].keys())

    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(result)
```

Comment: I got this error: (I am using Python 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PROJECTS/Conversion.py", line 30, in <module>
    x['value2'] = float(x['value1']) * 1000
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: That means something in your value column is not a valid float.

Comment: I got the error because of blank rows in my CSV file. Thanks for your help